# Wordpress on MVC site gives 403 access denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, http-status-code-403, virtual-directory

This is really frustrating. I've spent half a day trying to do something that should be simple. I'm almost there.

I want to add a wordpress blog to an MVC4 site, running on a web hosting server. I found a good blog [here](http://abbottps.com/2011/05/16/how-to-integrate-a-wordpress-and-a-net-web-application-on-iis7/) to do that.

Then I encountered problems with the web.config file being inherited, I found a good solution [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Aug/11/IISASPNET-Settings-and-Virtual-Directory-Inheritance).

That worked, but now I am receiving a 403 error. I am on web hosting so I have limited access to the IIS.

Does anybody have a solution??

Comment: You can move wordpress in subdirectory and add rule only for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up trying to deploy using the web matrix and instead found a wordpress extenstion that installs as part of the hosting.

Seemed to have done the trick.